# Outputting elapsed time on a report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I want to print start, end and elapsed time on the report but nothing seems to work.

```
="Elapsed: " + CStr(Now - CDate(Globals!ExecutionTime))
```

throws an error while

```
=Now - CDate(Globals!ExecutionTime)
```

prints elapsed time. I need to incorporate elasped time into a larger sentence. FormatDateTime throws an error re System.TimeSpan cannot be converted to Date.

What is the correct formula to print a string of how long the report took to generate?

I know that a workaround is to keep elapsed time in its own text box, but formatting requirements call for one concatenated string of all three times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might give you some ideas:

```
="Start: " & Globals!ExecutionTime.ToString() & vbcrlf
    & "End: " & Now().ToString() & vbcrlf
    & "Elapsed: " & DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute
            , Globals!ExecutionTime
            , Now()) mod 60
        & ":"
        & Right("0" & DateDiff(DateInterval.Second
                , Globals!ExecutionTime
                ,  Now()) mod 60
            , 2)
```

This gives a result of:

[image]

Which looks like what you might be after.

I'm just using `vbcrlf` as a line break.

The most important part is the `Elapsed` part, which uses `DateDiff` to get the difference between the two datetimes to get minute and second portions and displays this as `mm:ss`. You could adapt to your specific needs.

Comment: The only issue with DateDiff solution is that I need elapsed time precision of milliseconds and there is no corresponding DateInterval for that. Converting `Now - CDate(Globals!ExecutionTime)` to string would have just fit the goal, but i guess the offshore contractors did not care.